# Joining\relating\connecting 4 feature class together?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, relates, connection

How can I join\relate\connect  communities\UMP\BuiltUP\Admin boundaries?

Could you please consider the following scenario:

1. I have a feature class with a name “community “ which I consider it the main layer in may work, so I relate it to more than one table and it has many information about the community.

   [image]
2. Then I have three other feature classes each one is stored in a deferent file geodatabase ( built-up area, UMP urban master plan, and Administrative boundary).

   [image]

Now how could I join\relate\connect the three feature classes (built-up area, UMP, and Administrative boundary) to the (community) feature class so that when I identify the community point I can get the whole results from all feature class?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got you,you have common field among tables so better to use **Join** command and export the result to get a combined feature(composite).
This will not add geometry to the composite but only features' attributes only.

[image: join]

**N.B.If you are working with lot of data then take different approach, i mean you need to use RDBMS where you will link both table using Primary/Foreign Key.BTW there is a relationship feature class in geodatabase you can use it too.**

Comment: Thanks msi_g, but as you see in the following images I cant know form which layer is the field came             ![snapshot1](http://s17.postimg.org/h0hwp770f/Clip_4.jpg)                                       ![snapshot2](http://s21.postimg.org/t16ns93lz/Clip_5.jpg)

Comment: Then add a field in each layer's table that tells about layer(e.g. layer name) then join.

Comment: Many thanks msi_g fo your prompt help, I am getting more greedy with this issue, it seems that your first method works will with me but let me ask you How could I relate all layers together so when I identify the build up or the UMPs I can get all the records of other layers dynamically

Comment: I already answered( adding new field e.g. for UMP feature class add a field after Ref field, and name it say UMP the this field will appear in the picture you attached http://s21.postimg.org/t16ns93lz/Clip_5.jpg after Ref field thus you can track the layers..

Comment: Sorry mis_g I didn't clarify myself, what I wanted to say that is there any way to remain the four layers connected and share the same attributes, for example communities layer is related to many tables, could I relate the UMPs and Builtup layers so they stay connected to the commuinties layer whatever I updated the communities it will be reflected dynamically to other layers